# change css class property increment

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small question!
I'am trying to change css width property using JavaScript like this:

```js
document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = "80%";
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 1px;
}

#progressvalue {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #05e35e;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"> 
  <div id="progressvalue"></div>
</div>
```

But instead of 80% in JavaScript code, I want to increase the width value by 20%.
Like (width = width + 20%)
I want to apply this changing once (So I can use it mutiple times using other conditions), and this is why I need it like this (width = width + 20%)

Comment: How are you calling that JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript HTML DOM
DOM is JavaScript type

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question; I meant to ask: what happens in the browser that leads to that line of JavaScript being executed?

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding, my code is working. but instead of fixed value I want the value to be increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to read the element's `style.width` property, by keeping only the numeric part of it and adding it to your step (eg 20%).

```js
const step = 5;

const updateProgress = () => {
  const currentWidth = Number(document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width.replace( "%", ""));
  
  if (currentWidth>=100) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = `${currentWidth+step}%`;
  } 
}
```

You can check this out in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/teresapap/pen/WNdKmrw).

Comment: Thank you so much.
I just need one smal thing to edit.
The code I want to reach is combined with a liquid code.
insted av button I want the code to just run by it self.
the idea is like this:
If Liquid condition happend ==> apply this Javascript code 
So I don't want to apply the code using button.

Comment: I'm not sure what a liquid condition is, but can you try to call the `updateProgress` function when the condition is true? Like: 
 Liquid condition happend ==> `updateProgress()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
//offsetWidth : returns the width of the element
var element_width=document.getElementById("progressvalue").offsetWidth

document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width =element_width + (20*element_width/100) +'px' ;
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing happened   https://codepen.io/saliem-antoun/pen/ExopOEe
It should return 70% width, did I miss anything?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add px to the new width,I just modified you can see again

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do some animation right ? If so you can use recursivity with setTimeout:

```js
function progress(val) {
    val += 20;

    document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = val + "%";
    if (val < 100) // To stop the loop when progress bar is full
        setTimeout(function () {
            progress(val);
        }, 1000)
}
progress(0); // Start the animation
```

Answer (score 1):

This will increase by 20% every 0.5 seconds.

```
let percent = 0;

setInterval(() => 
{
    if(percent > 100) {
        clearInterval();
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("progressvalue").style.width = percent + "%";
    percent += 20;
}, 500);
```

Comment: It is keep increasing the value..Until it is 100%
I want to change the value once

Comment: If you want to increase infinitely remove the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
    var el = document.getElementById("progressvalue");

    var elementWidth = el.style.width;

    var newWidth = `${20+parseInt(elementWidth.substring(0, elementWidth.length-1))}%`
    el.style.width=newWidth;
```

Assuming that you have set the width of the element initially to a percent value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Change the width</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  let progress = document.getElementById("progressvalue");
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(progress, null).getPropertyValue('width');
  let currentSize = parseFloat(style);
  progress.style.width = (currentSize + 20) + '%';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current width of `<div id="progressvalue"></div>`, put it in a variable and add `20` and reassign that value to `<div id="progressvalue"></div>`.